# Getting comma inside value of long type at freemarker page

Tags: java, freemarker

I am having some strange problem and its really frustating me. I have a list of Car bean in request attribute -

```
List<Car> cars = myservice.getCars();
request.setAttribute("cars", cars);
```

When I print the car ids (long type), it gives me correct value -

```
for(Car car: cars) {
 System.out.println(car.id);
}
// It gives me - 11231, 11245, 11253
```

But when I am trying to get same on freemarker page resutl.ftl, its giving me values as -

```
11,231 
11,245
11,253
```

The code is -

```
<#list cars as car>
 <span>Car Id:</span>${car.id}
<#list>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Formatting of numbers appears to be locale-sensitive.  This FAQ entry appears to give a fix:

http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/app_faq.html#faq_number_grouping

From that page (and that page alone, I'd never heard of Freemarker before your question), it seems that this might do what you want:

```
<span>Car Id:</span>${car.id?c}
```

Or you could adjust your locale settings or number format to be something more like you expect.  Exactly how to do that is detailed in the link above.